How can i zip the files in an Azure function app to local c:\ drive?
I am trying to zip the contents of a function app like the following
       az functionapp deployment source config-zip --name <function-app-name> --resource-group <resource-group-name> --src /site/wwwroot --output "c:\temp\func.zip"

but it gives error:
 No such file or directory: 'c:\\temp\\func.zip'

How can i zip the files ?
Even if i try to list the files using
 az functionapp file list --name <function-app-name> --resource-group <resource-group-name> --path /site/wwwroot

it also gives an error:
 ERROR: 'file' is misspelled or not recognized by the system.

